# Xamarin UI Text - How to tap into attributed string (hyberlink) in UITextView

Tags: xamarin, uitextview, xamarin.uitest

I'm doing with Xamarin UITest, I need to tap in an attributed string (or hyperlink) within a UITextView, the UITextView is similar with this image:

[I don't have enough reputation to upload image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyspb.png)

Is there any solution for me to tap (I think it should be tapped by TapCoordinates function)
Thank you very much!

Comment: It doesn't look like the image is showing but it may be my machine.  Please provide a code example or pseudo code for what you want because it's quite confusing.

Comment: What happens when you manually click the attributed string? Another app page is launched? A web browser/external app/...?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Sorry for this confusion! I want to tap a hyperlink (string with red or blue color) in a UITextView, and I want to get the position (x,y) of this text to use TapCoordinates function in Xamarin UITest

Comment: @SushiHangover It can be any! In my case, It will open the Safari to load this link!